# How to update the global variable in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Some application state information need to be stored in an Angular service so as to be globally accessed.

```
app.value('identity', {});
```

Then in a controller of my first view after log in. I make a GET api call to collect application state info from the server side. In the success callback, transfer the data into my global variable (service).

```
function successCallback(data) {
    identity.username = data.username;
    identity.email = data.email;
}
```

I assumed the `identity` will hold the data throughout my application. But it is not the case! In my other views, I inject `identity` into the controller

```
app.controller('anotherController', ['identity', anotherController];
function anotherController(identity){
    // access identity here.
    $scope.username=identity.username;
}
```

The first time I came to that view. `username` is correctly displayed on the page. But after a refresh, it appears the `identity` is null again! What can we do to make the value really persistent?

Comment: "after a refresh" do you mean an F5-style refresh?

Comment: Services are singletons in an angular app, but the whole app restarts with an F5. You could maintain the state client side with `localStorage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pointing the `var` identity to a new object that angular doesn't know about so it can't take that new value to another controller. I'd assign the callback's response to a property on identity:

```
app.value('identity', { data: null });
```

...

```
funciton successCallback(data) {
  // here, not overwriting identity, but editing a property
  identity.data = data;
}
```

controller:

```
app.controller('anotherController', ['identity', anotherController];
  function anotherController($scope, identity){

  // add the svc to the scope so you can access its properties later
  $scope.identity = identity;
}
```

html template:

```
{{ identity.data | json }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Found another issue after marking it as the correct answer. I have updated the question a bit.